# How to connect a timer to a different thread events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, timer

I have an application in which I have to make some leds blink with some colours and (for debug) an ellipse. According to an event-driven state I have to change the blink colour.
The timer is always the same:

```
DispatcherTimer ledTimer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
```

but its behaviour changes according to the ledState value. And that one is changed according to external events.

```
public eLedState _ledState;
EventHandler ehLedTimer = null;
eLedState LedState
{
    get { return _ledState; }
    set
    {
        ledTimer.Stop();
        ledTimer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

        if (ehLedTimer != null)
            ledTimer.Tick -= ehLedTimer;

        int counter = 0;
        _ledState = value;

        string WHITE = "255,255,255,1,0";
        string GREEN = "0,255,0,1,0";
        string RED = "255,0,0,1,0";
        string BLUE = "0,0,255,1,0";
        string YELLOW = "255,255,0,1,0";
        string OFF = "0,0,0";

        Serializers.Logger.WriteLog("LedState = " + LedState);

        switch (_ledState)
        {
            case eLedState.IDLE: SetLeds(WHITE); break;
            case eLedState.CONNECTING:
                ehLedTimer = (sender2, args) =>
                {
                    switch (counter)
                    {
                        case 0: SetLeds(RED); counter++; break;
                        case 1: SetLeds(GREEN); counter++; break;
                        case 2: SetLeds(BLUE); counter = 0; break;
                    }
                };
                break;
            case eLedState.RUNNING:
                ehLedTimer = (sender2, args) => { SetLeds(YELLOW); }; <-----HERE PROBLEM
                break;
            case eLedState.OUT_TOLERANCE:
                ehLedTimer = (sender2, args) =>
                {
                    switch (counter)
                    {
                        case 0: SetLeds(RED); counter++; break;
                        case 1: SetLeds(WHITE); counter = 0; break;
                    }
                };
                break;
            case eLedState.IN_TOLERANCE:
                ehLedTimer = (sender2, args) =>
                {
                    switch (counter)
                    {
                        case 0: SetLeds(GREEN); counter++; break;
                        case 1: SetLeds(WHITE); counter = 0; break;
                    }
                };
                break;
            case eLedState.PAUSED:
                ehLedTimer = (sender2, args) =>
                {
                    switch (counter)
                    {
                        case 0: SetLeds(WHITE); counter++; break;
                        case 1: SetLeds(OFF); counter = 0; break;
                    }
                };
                ledTimer.Start(); break;
            case eLedState.ERROR:
                ledTimer.Tick += (sender2, args) =>
                {
                    switch (counter)
                    {
                        case 0: SetLeds(RED); counter++; break;
                        case 1: SetLeds(OFF); counter = 0; break;
                    }
                };
                break;
            case eLedState.AWAITING_AUTOSTART:
                ledTimer.Tick += (sender2, args) =>
                {
                    switch (counter)
                    {
                        case 0: SetLeds(RED); counter++; break;
                        case 1: SetLeds(GREEN); counter = 0; break;
                    }
                };
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        ledTimer.Tick += ehLedTimer;
        ledTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

So in short my idea is: when a change is detected stop the previous timer behaviour, change it and the resume and start.

But something doesn't work. It acts weirdly and trying to be more specific it never gets yellow.

If I put a breakpoint where the ledstate is set to running I see that it is hit but never enters in the SetLeds routine. This running state is set from another thread could this be the reason?

**So in short when the running event is fired the timer doesn't tick.**

Thank you in advance for any help

Patrick

Comment: When the LedState setter is called in another thread, the DispatcherTimer is created with affinity to that thread. It will then call its Tick handler in that thread, which is not the UI thread and hence can't access any UI elements representing your LEDs. Besides that, I find your approach *far* too complicated. Why not simply evaluate the LedState property in each call of a single Tick handler? It doesn't cost any performance at all.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your hint led me to the correct solution. You might want to post it as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a break point at some other point in your code & then check the ledTimer.Dispatcher.Thread & you will probably see that "this.ledTimer.Dispatcher.Thread.ApartmentState' threw an exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException".

You need to set the new state from the same thread the timer belongs to - you could get the timer to set it with it's own Dispatcher (or any other object on the Gui thread) :

```
ledTimer.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => LedState = eLedState.RUNNING);
```

Comment: Sorry but I had already done that and as I said it acted weirdly

Comment: You will need to put the break point at some other point in the code that will be triggered AFTER the state is set to running - then you will be able to see what has happened to the new timer thread. I managed to get your code running by setting the state as I suggested.